# Kibana: limit the amount of searched indexes (Smart_index_limit)

Tags: kibana

I have a problem of getting the error: "OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space]".

My thought was to see if there is a way to limit the amount of searched indexes. So on the internet I actually found out that there used to be an setting "Smart_index_limit". I cannot find this in Kibana 3.1.0 .

Is there still a way to limit the amount of searched indexes?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will answer your question. One way is once u have multiple query and it is displayed on either pie or bar, than u can click on the configuration of the pie or bar depending on which u are using to display your query,then go to the queries panel. U will see all,pinned,unpinned and selected. That is where u can choose selected and than click on those u want them to be displayed on your pie or bar. Same goes for term.

Another way is that u can click on the field that u don't wanna see, it will be displayed under filtering panel on your kibana. That is where u click on that filtering and under the tab term, there is 3 thing which is must,mustNOT and either. So u can click on mustNOT and for that part it won't be displayed anymore on your table.

Hope this answers ur question. :D